# Probability of winning a lottery - Question

Tags: probability

In a lottery draw from 1-49.

How would I find the probability that at least one person will win the lottery
out of a pool of 100,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P$(No one wins)$=(\frac{48}{49})^{100,000}$

Simply subtract this from 1.

Answer (score 0):

Find the probability that no one wins and subtract this from 1.